# How do I use gdb when I'm using a debug version of Python?

Tags: python, gdb

My version of gdb is linked against my system python, but I am currently working with a special debug build of python.  Hence, gdb fails to launch correctly, with errors like this:

```
$ gdb
gdb: Symbol `_Py_ZeroStruct' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
gdb: Symbol `PyBool_Type' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
gdb: Symbol `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
gdb: Symbol `PyFloat_Type' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
gdb: Symbol `_Py_TrueStruct' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
gdb: Symbol `_Py_NoneStruct' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
Segmentation fault
```

...or maybe errors like this:

```
gdb: symbol lookup error: gdb: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromEncodedObject
```

How can I use gdb even though a non-system version of Python exists on my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer in the [rootpy Documentation](https://github.com/rootpy/rootpy/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.rst):

> The way around this is to preload the correct library by setting
>   LD_PRELOAD, and then unsetting it before your program is executed. For
>   example, this will debug my-program-to-debug:
>
> ```
> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so gdb -ex 'set environ LD_PRELOAD' --args my-program-to-debug
> ```
>
> Note that you need to set LD_PRELOAD to the right version of python
>   that gdb was compiled against, which you can find with ldd $(which
>   gdb) from a fresh environment.

Comment: Quick followup: For some reason, I have to load the module `python-2.7.6/Tools/gdb/libpython.py` (from the downloaded tarball) to my `sys.path` or else special python commands like `py-bt` etc. commands aren't available. (`Undefined command: "py-bt".  Try "help".`) One way to do load that module can be seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14905356/162094)