# Can't launch debug - C in VS code on Linux

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-code, gdb

Let me preface this, I am very new to linux and to working on a non-IDE based setup.

I am trying to debug a very simple C program using vs code version 1.55
I unloaded all modules beforehand, so vs code can load appropriate default gcc & gdb versions (which it did, GCC 8.2)
I am following the VS code getting started [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux) for setting up and everything seems very straight forward until I try to debug.
I use the default settings as instructed, the file builds successfully but then I get the below

`/usr/bin/gdb: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/gdb: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromEncodedObject`

please note that I cannot rebuild python with  ucs4 enabled as suggested in another thread as I have no root access. however I can change VS code version to an earlier one if this will help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951429/how-do-i-use-gdb-when-im-using-a-debug-version-of-python) solution with LD_PRELOAD. Set it as env variable before launching vscode.

Comment: Thank you.
when I try to run "LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 gdb -ex 'set environ LD_PRELOAD' --args my-program-to-debug" in my terminal I get "LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0: Command not found."
Should I add set or export before it?

Comment: Yes  export it. When it is exported you Can use just gdb without prepending LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: I tried setting it to the libpython path in `ldd /user/gdb` then `export` then launch vs code but I still getting the same error message
note: I tried to `echo $LD_PRELOAD` before I launched vs code but it returned nothing. so maybe I am doing something wrong in setting it?

Comment: @T0maas it turned to be a 2 part problem where your help solved the first part. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue is specific to my environment but I will post the answer anyway as it may face someone else.

So this for me was 2 separate issues:
First gdb doesn't start and second vs code can't start gdb.
To check if this is the case try to launch gdb from terminal (not vs code) by typing `gdb` in the terminal (after loading gdb if needed), I was receiving the error above

Solution to this part is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951429/how-do-i-use-gdb-when-im-using-a-debug-version-of-python) as T0maas thankfully suggested above
Steps for linux newbies:

1. ldd gdb (or /usr/bin/gdb) (with vs_code loaded)
   from step one get the python library path
2. unload all modules
3. load gdb
4. LD_PRELOAD=<python path from 1>
5. bash -c "export LD_PRELOAD"
6. load vs_code
7. load gdb

After the above steps writing gdb in the terminal should start gdb

Part 2:
The rest of the problem was when I tried to launch debugging session through the GUI of vs_code (still produced the same error)
In the terminal (after loading gdb) type `whereis gdb`
For me this produced multiple directories the first of which was /usr/bin/gdb (this is the default used in vs_code launch.json)
Changing that directory in the launch.json file to a different one of the other directories solved the second part of the problem for me.